# What does it mean to grant rescission on terms?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

Kindly see the embolded phrase below.

> #### 18.5 Remedy

> There is no tort of undue influence. As a result, C cannot recover damages from D if a claim
> in undue influence is successful. This is sometimes criticised, and it may be that in time
> undue influence will evolve to be recognised as a wrong which triggers compensation.<sup>45</sup>
> After all, in *Libya Investment Authority v Goldman Sachs International*, Rose J recognised
> that the stronger party owes certain duties to the weaker party in a relationship of influence.
> A breach of duty is a wrong, and the normal response to a civil wrong is damages.
>       Nevertheless, the traditional and orthodox view is that the only remedy for undue influence
> is rescission.<sup>46</sup> It is worth highlighting that the usual bars of rescission apply.<sup>47</sup> So, for
> example, in *Allcard v Skinner*, the claim for undue influence was barred because of the claimant’s
> delay in bringing her claim (laches). Similarly, in the three-party scenarios discussed
> in Chapter 18.4, if the bank is not put on inquiry and purchases its rights in good faith
> without notice of the undue influence, C will not be able to rescind the transaction since that
> would unfairly prejudice the bank. But if the bank is put on inquiry, then it will have notice
> of the undue influence, and as a result the rights it acquires will not be sufficient to prevent rescission unless that bank has taken reasonable steps to ensure that C has not entered into
> the transaction as a result of undue influence. In *Etridge*, Lord Scott said:<sup>48</sup>

> > If contractual consent has been procured by undue influence or misrepresentation for which a
> > party to the contract is responsible, the other party, the victim, is entitled, subject to the usual
> > defences of change of position, affirmation, delay etc, to avoid the contract.

> There have been cases where **rescission has been shown to be a flexible remedy that has been
> granted on terms.**<sup>49</sup> For example, in *Cheese v Thomas*,<sup>50</sup> the agreement was between C, aged
> 85, and his great-nephew, D, to buy a house to live in together. They purchased a house for
> £83,000; C contributed £43,000 in cash, and D contributed the rest of the money by way of
> a mortgage. D defaulted on the mortgage payments, and the house was sold for £55,000.
> The court held that the relationship between C and D was one of trust and confidence, and
> that the transaction was manifestly disadvantageous to C, since he paid a substantial sum of
> money for a ‘seriously insecure’ right that tied him to that particular house.

> > 45 See eg L Ho, ‘Undue Influence and Equitable Compensation’ in P Birks and F Rose (eds), *Restitution and
> > Equity* (Mansfield Press, 2000) vol 1. Similar arguments are often made in the context of duress, which is also not, in itself, a wrong that leads to damages.
> > 46 For general discussion of rescission, see Chapter 16.4.
> > 47 See Chapter 16.4.4.
> > 48 *Etridge*, [144]. 49 Though partial rescission is impossible: see Chapter 16.4.4.1.
> > 50 [1994] 1 WLR 129.

*JC Smith's The Law of Contract* 2021 3 ed, pp 285-6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What does it mean to grant rescission on terms?**

When setting aside a contract, the court may may apply what it called "practical justice” in [*Salt v Stratsone 2015*](https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWCA/Civ/2015/745.html) which can include ordering rescission on terms that allow for compensation for any unfairness that would otherwise result.